# Angular js Provider returns unknownProvider, when it is declared on basic angular example

Tags: angularjs

File inclusion in the index.html is

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/providers/jokeService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
```

app.js is the main declaration of the module, and the route declaration with accompanying controller and template:

```
angular.module('jsekoApp', [ 'ui', 'ngRoute' ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      })
  });
```

jokeService.js is factory Provider

```
angular.module('jsekoApp')
 .factory('JokeService', function($resource) {
   return $resource('data.json');
});
```

and the mainController.js is a controller, with the jokeService injected into it:

```
angular.module('jsekoApp')
  .controller('MainController', function MainController($scope, JokeService) {

    console.log(JokeService);

    JokeService.get(function(data){
      $scope.jokes = data;
    });

    $scope.jokeTypeList = function(){...};
  });
```

My understanding is that all 3 (app.js, controller, and factoryProvider) should be declared in the html.

Why am I getting the unknown Provider error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- JokeService
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20JokeService

Also, anyway to get the stack to show where the error is coming from?  it just shows the errors in the angular.js file, but which 'JokeService' are they referring to?  This might have helped me debug this on my own.

Comment: The `$resource` service is now in the [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) module, which isn't loaded in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS is complaining about the missing $resource service. You forgot to include the angular-resource.js file, and to make your main module depend on the ngResource module, as explained in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource).